# Problem with react-table GlobalFilter when typing

Tags: reactjs, react-table

the problem I'm facing with react-table and GlobalFilter is that when I type something in the input it only allows one letter at a time. When you start writing just type the first letter and then lost the focus on the input.

I have followed the documentation from react-table but is not working as expected: https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGlobalFilter

Here is the code that i've tried https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-tharp-sllqnv?file=/src/App.js

I tried to use the autoFocus property in the input but is not what I want

Any help will be great for me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you put `DefaultColumnFilter` inside the `TablaGenericaConFiltros` body. So on each render there is a new component!

Move `DefaultColumnFilter` (and other stuff for safety) to the top level and everything will work.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-frog-nxw6p1?file=/src/App.js)